# enviar email ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quiero que cuando guarde verifique si es `true` y enviar el correo, pero el correo no llega.

**reunion.rb**

```
after_save :autorizar

def  autorizar
  if self.auto = true 
    ReunionMailer.autorizar_email(Reunion.find(self.id)).deliver 
  end
end
```

**setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",        #este es el dominio
  :user_name            => "correo@gmail.com",
  :password             => "lucas",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**reunion_mailer.rb**

```
class ReunionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def autorizar_email(reunion)
    @reunion = reunion
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @reunion.email, subject: 'AUTORIZACION')
  end
end
```

**application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**autorizar_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <p>
      Esto es un ejemplo de envío de correos en una aplicación de Ruby on Rails<br>
      ya  esta autorizando
    </p>

    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'mail'
```

[image: mirar la imagen]

Comment: Te dejo un enlace de la versión inglesa en la que se resuelve tu duda, un saludo. [Send mail ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309345/how-to-send-mail-in-ruby)

Comment: @Orz hola tu vesz  algo en mi codigo por que no funciona, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra el log?

Comment: @Gerry lo acabe de montar.

Comment: ¿Es todo lo que muestra? ¿Qué version de Rails usas?

Comment: @Gerry  ruby 2.3.1 rails 5.1.1 , gracias

Comment: Intenta con `deliver_now` en lugar de `deliver`. Para ver los errores en el log abre el archivo _config/environments/development.rb_ y verifica que tengas esta línea: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` (deberás reiniciar tu servidor de Rails si modificas este archivo).

Comment: @Gerry ya me dio, ponga la repuesta. para dar chulito me puedes  explicar por que agregando estas lineas me dio.muchas gracias

Comment: @Gerry si fuera production tambien se le pone true. gracias

Comment: No, en producción no se recominda pues puede afectar la experincia del usuario en caso que el envío falle; sin embargo podrías ponerlo para depurar un error (que no puedas reproducir en desarrollo) y, una vez que se arregle el error, quitarlo.

Comment: O bien, podrías dejarlo pero deberías preparar tu aplicación para manejar las exepciones que puedan derivarse de un error de envío (podrías cacharlas con `rescue` y loggear el error, así no rompes la experiencia del usuario).

Comment: @Gerry  uuummm ya  tienes un ejemplo como manejarla.gracias

Comment: @Gerry https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/4061-How-to-handle-exceptions-in-Rails-5 esto me sirve pero la vinculo con los correos, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `deliver` ha sido depreciado en *Rails 5* y sustituido por los métodos `deliver_now` (para enviar inmediatamente) y `deliver_later` (para enviar más tarde); por lo tanto intenta sustituir el uso de `deliver` con cualquiera de estas alternativas; por ejemplo:

```
def  autorizar
  if self.auto = true 
    ReunionMailer.autorizar_email(Reunion.find(self.id)).deliver_now
  end
end
```

---

Adicionalmente, *Rails* te da la opción de no generar excepciones cuando se genera un error al enviar un correo; esto es útil para evitar que la aplicación **en productivo**  muestre una pantalla de error al usuario (finalmente, el envío de correos generalmente no parte del flujo de la aplicación).

Sin embargo, es importante **habilitar esta opción desarrollo** permitiendo que sí se generen excepciones al fallar algún envío de correo, y así poder depurar el código con más facilidad; para habilitar esta opción debes agregar (en caso que no esté) la siguiente línea en el archivo *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Recuerda que siempre que se modifique este archivo se debe reiniciar el servidor de *Rails* para que los cambios tengan efecto.